# How do I calculate Logarithmic Negativity for the given bipartite state?

Tags: entanglement, measurement, entanglement-negativity

How can I calculate Logarithmic Negativity for the given state?

$\rho = \frac{1}{2} |0\rangle \langle0| \otimes |+\rangle \langle+| +\frac{1}{2} |+\rangle \langle+| \otimes |1\rangle \langle1| $

Comment: The state is separable hence its logarithmic negativity is zero.

Answer (score 2):

If we defined the [logarithmic negativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negativity_(quantum_mechanics)#Logarithmic_negativity) as $E_N(\rho)= \log_2 \|\rho^{\Gamma_A} \|_1$ then given that
$$\rho = \frac{1}{2} |0\rangle \langle0| \otimes |+\rangle \langle+| +\frac{1}{2} |+\rangle \langle+| \otimes |1\rangle \langle1|  = \begin{pmatrix} 1/4 & 1/4 & 0 & 0\\ 1/4 & 1/2 & 0 & 1/4\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1/4 & 0 & 1/4  \end{pmatrix}$$

and since  given a matrix $X$ then its partial transpose with respect to the first system $A$, $X^{\Gamma_A} $  is defined as
$$X = \begin{pmatrix} x_{11} & x_{12} & x_{13} & x_{14}\\ x_{21} & x_{22} & x_{23} & x_{24}\\ x_{31} & x_{32} & x_{33} & x_{34}\\x_{41} & x_{42} & x_{43} & x_{44}  \end{pmatrix} \hspace{0.5cm}  X^{\Gamma_A} = \begin{pmatrix} x_{11} & x_{12} & x_{31} & x_{32}\\ x_{21} & x_{22} & x_{41} & x_{42}\\ x_{13} & x_{14} & x_{33} & x_{34}\\x_{23} & x_{24} & x_{43} & x_{44}  \end{pmatrix} $$

we have that the partial transpose of $\rho$ with respect to the first system $A$ is itself. That is,  $\rho^{\Gamma_A} = \rho$. Hence, $\|\rho^{\Gamma_A}\|_1 = 1$ and thus $ \log_2 \|\rho^{\Gamma_A} \|_1 = \log_2(1) = 0$ where $\|\cdot\|_1$ is the trace norm, that is, the sum of the absolute value of the eigenvalues -- but since $\rho$ is a density matrix, all eigenvalues are positive, so itis just the trace (which equals $1$).

Comment: The $\|\cdot\|_1$ norm is the [trace norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Schatten_norms), which is the sum of the singular values and is different from the column 1-norm. Otherwise, this is correct. Note that we can simplify the calculation by observing that if $\rho$ is a separable state then $\rho^\Gamma$ is a state and therefore $\|\rho^\Gamma\|_1=1$. Consequently, $E_N(\rho)=0$ for all separable states.

Comment: Thanks @Nobert Schuch for the edit!